# Delete Windows 7 cached credentials for all the users

Tags: user-profiles, credentials

I know how to delete my profile's cached credentials. The issue comes when theres is a user that get locked out again and again due to a credential cached within another user profile.

If you go to the Event viewer, System log, you can see the event id 14 saying about an invalid password, likely from a cached credential. The problem is that the event ID doesn't say the user profile where the credential is cached.

Is there any way to identify the user profile where the credential is cached. What is more, is it possible to delete remotely cached credentials?

Thank you.